# Redis Transaction with high throughput

Tags: stackexchange.redis

My question is about a best practise.

Im sending all simple user page view to redis. What i want to do is for every user,

There should be a list of pages that user ve looked.
That list needs to have a limit of max 20 items. 
Lastly, that list needs to have an expiration time (key expiration).
The implemantation is (Im using StackExchange.Redis for applications):

```
  var transaction = _cache.CreateTransaction();

                transaction.ListLeftPushAsync(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), When.Always, CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
                transaction.KeyExpireAsync(key, TimeSpan.FromDays(Constants.Constants.TopnUserCacheDurationinDays), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);

                if (new Random().Next(7) == 6)
                {
                    transaction.ListTrimAsync(key, 0, Constants.Constants.TopNUserHistoryLimit, CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
                }

                return transaction.ExecuteAsync();
```

The question is, is this implemantation is good for my needs. I feel that smth is not right. Because there are ~300 requests in a second. So im sending  1 request with 3 jobs 300 times in a second.

Any suggestions?